# Third box locked value JS

Tags: javascript, html

I am using an javascript function script in html to get the product of two input boxes into third.
HTML:-

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputBuyPrice" placeholder="0.0" name="price" oninput="calculate()">
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputBuyAmount" placeholder="0.0" name="amount" oninput="calculate()">
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputBuyTotal" placeholder="0.0" name="total" oninput="calculate()">
```

And the javascript:-

```
  <script>
  function calculate() {
var myBox1 = document.getElementById('inputBuyAmount').value; 
var myBox2 = document.getElementById('inputBuyPrice').value;
var result = document.getElementById('inputBuyTotal'); 
var numb = myBox1 * myBox2;
numb = numb.toFixed(8);
result.value = numb;
}
 </script>
```

Now everything is working fine. But value of total gets locked by product of amount and price. I don't want it to be readonly but input that's value can be changed by user.

Comment: Then don't execute `calculate()` on it?

Comment: But I need price*amount as well and it should reflect on total

Comment: *"I don't want it to be readonly but input that's value can be changed by user."* What should happen when the user changes the total? It seems very odd to allow the user to do that.

Comment: Why do you want allow input in total box that should be calculated from amount*price? What do you want to achieve?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder it recalculates and shows in total

Comment: @maximelian1986 Simple thing amount*price to be shown in total, but total can be changed manually and incase again price or amount change , product should be shown in total

Comment: Some what like the tradebook orders in stock exchanges

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I will make script for total/price=amount also so no worries about that

Comment: May be you want to recalculate price when changing total, then you need another function to do so.  But you have something wrong in that logic. IMHO total should be a label.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a comment you've said:

> Simple thing amount*price to be shown in total, but total can be changed manually and incase again price or amount change , product should be shown in total

If that's what you want, just remove the `oninput="calculate()"` on `inputBuyTotal`. That will allow the user to change it however they want, but then changing `inputBuyPrice` or `inputBuyAmount` will replace what they changed it to with the product of those fields.

---

*(I wish the shops I buy from let me manually change the total amount to pay... )*

Comment: Thanks works :) I will add an function to recalculate price and amount ;)

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
oninput="calculate()"
```

to

```
oninput="calculateAmount()"
```

and add function calculateAmount()

Comment: Where is the function calculateAmount() in script but